Approximate irrational numbers using rational numbers from up and below
Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ be an irrational number. It is well-known that for any integer $n$, there exists a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ with $|q|\leq n$ such that
$$|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{qn}.$$
My question is the following: Is there a similar result that one can approximate $\alpha$ by $\frac{p_1}{q_1}<\alpha<\frac{p_2}{q_2}$ satisfying similar conditions for both $\frac{p_1}{q_1}$ and $\frac{p_2}{q_2}$?

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \                              $yes.

You might look at Niven, "Diophantine Approximations", sec. 1.3: Asymmetic Approximations.

Thanks a lot! @RobertIsrael
